# BCP pausing during upload - continues after ctrl-C

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I've been uploading to a TSQL server with BCP and the upload intermittently stops. When I know it has stopped I can press ctrl-C and it will carry on instead of cancelling the upload. This doesn't lose any data, the correct number of rows will be inserted. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening? The volume is in the millions and I don't want to babysit the upload even though it uploads at around 50,000 per second when functioning properly.

The command is:

```
bcp [server].[schema].[table] in "some.csv" -T -S [server name, port] -c F1 -t "¬" b 50000 -a65535 -h TABLOCK
```

The same error occurs without the `-a65535 -h TABLOCK` section but that is there to increase upload speeds.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont think so, the problem Baz1nga was having was to do with redirecting to std output but I'm running all of my commands directly from windows in Powershell

Comment: In light of the answer its now clear that the question nor the answer has anything to do with sql or bcp

Answer (score -1):

It appears the bcp pauses when you click on it. It seems to also happen when unattended but I haven't been able to recreate that scenario for the past 24 hours so perhaps it was all the clicking error. This appears to be a Powershell error where clicking on the shell will interrupt any program you're running.

Odd

Comment: I voted down because this is now found to be unrelated to bcp. Entering in command shells in windows is a common way to pause feedback esp scrolling feedback.